# Cross gradle dependancy between main and test

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew, gradle-eclipse

I have gradle project and there are two sources src/main/java and src/test/java.
Practically the code in main is used in test. It's fine.

But I want to stop dependency other way round means if someone wants to access test method of src/test/java in any of the code of src/main/java. It should not be allowed. It should give compile time error.

If anyone know please share the way.

Comment: Can you post your "build.gradle" file?

Comment: What you describe is the default behavior for Gradle (test not included in main compile).  Eclipse may be doing something to add the test files onto the ClassPath.  You can verify this by running gradle on the command line outside of Eclipse and see if you get the compile errors.